# Why does TFS add "_1" to the folder name when I create a new project and add to source control?

Tags: tfs

Whenever I create a new project, and either check the box to add it to source control, or manually add it after it is created, the name of the folder that appears in source control has a _1 appended to the name.  On my machine, the folder name is what I want, but not in TFS.  So if I create a project called "Foo", then in TFS it will be "Foo_1". Also, after I check in pending changes, the Rename option on the shortcut menu is greyed out.

Everything works, but it looks stupid, and everyone else using TFS does not have this issue.  I searched but was not able to find anything quite like this.

Comment: Did this occurs in every team project  with your account  including the old project?  Or only with this new project ?

Comment: It only happens when I create a new project and put it in source control.  It doesn't happen for the 3 other developers.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to add a project or folder to the source control, **but they already exist in the source control project with the same name**. If you insist on selecting *Add*  the item, it wants to **add the item with an _1 on the end.**

You may need to confirm that the item or project already exists and doesn't need to be re-added.

Most likely is another mapping was added to your Workspace “Working Folders” section that had a direct link between the new Source Control Folder and your Local Folder.  *(Check **workspace -Edit -Advance**)*
[image]

Solution: Remove the erroneous mapping in local workspace.